# passar dados do jquery para o controller e retornar valores

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Preciso que quando textbox perder o foco, passar o valor que tiver nele para meu controller, no meu controller eu vou retornar um objeto para o jquery, assim eu consigo preencher os outros campos.

Gostaria de saber como eu poderia fazer isso?

Meu método do controller é esse:

```
public UserValid RetornaUsuario(String matricula)
{
    UserValid valid = new UserValid();
    UserValidDAO dao = new UserValidDAO();
    valid = dao.Busca(matricula);

    return valid;
}
```

Estava tentando fazer algo desta forma:

```
function PassarMatricula() {
    var parametros = {
        _matricula : $('#txtMatricula').val(),      
    };

    $.ajax({
        url : 'Home/RetornaUsuario',
        datatype : 'json',
        contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        type : "POST",
        data : JSON.stringify(parametros),
        success : function(data) {  

        },
        error : function(error) {
        }
    });    
}
```

Comment: Você pode fazer usando Ajax. Retorne um Json e preencha. Poste o html e Jquery que tem tentado usar.

Comment: Você só tem esse código?

Answer (score 1):

Como dito nos comentários pelo @Marconi, você pode usar Ajax para fazer isso.

Primeiro você irá enviar os dados para sua Action por Ajax, depois fazer o que necessita e retornar os dados via `json` para sua view. Um exemplo seria assim:

**Controller**

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult BuscarCep(string cep)
        {
            var endereco = db.Endereco.FirstOrFefault(x => x.cep == cep);
            return Json(endereco, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

**View**

```
<script>
        $('#txtCep').on('blur', function() {
            var cep= $('#txtCep').val();
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("BuscarCep","Endereco")?cep=' + extensao,
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (data) {
                    //Preenche os inputs com os valores retornados aqui.
                    $('#txtEndereco').val(data.Endereco);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: @Marconi Não sei exatamente o que ele precisa. Com `ActionResult` ele pode retornar o que desejar. json, partial view, etc.

Comment: Entendi.Removendo comentarios.

Comment: @Marconi Poderia deixar. Para falar a verdade essa é uma ótima pergunta, caso queira saber o real motivo de cada tipo.

Comment: Vdd, faz a pergunta lá. rsrsrs

Comment: Vou tentar implementar desta maneira